# Python как посмотреть список открытых окон

Tags: python, python-3.x

как с помощью python посмотреть открытые приложения-окна?

Comment: Расскажите немного больше, что вы хотите сделать и какая у вас ОС.

Comment: @S.Nick Я пишу приложение на Python, которое должно иметь возможность отправлять ключи или текст в другое приложение. Windows 10 home

Comment: Попробуйте почитать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55547940/how-to-get-a-list-of-the-name-of-every-open-window и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65717815/how-can-i-make-my-pyqt5-app-oney-one-instance

Comment: или это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54827918/get-list-of-running-windows-applications-using-python

Comment: @S.Nick спасибо помог!

Comment: main пожалуйста